# Why is my loop not exiting in Release but does in Debug?

Tags: c#

So I have a program that does a lot of Asynchronous commands (web calls, etc) and functions that it calls in parallel. To stop the Main loop from going off the rails and quitting before everything is done, I created a class variable, `static int die`, which counts the number of functions still in execution. Simplified/Naive task queuing, I suppose. Before invoking a function, I `die++;` and at the end of each function, `die--;`, with this sitting at the end of my Main() function:

```
             while (die > 0) { }
            Console.WriteLine("Writing Log File and Exiting");
} //End of Main()
```

And it works fine when running in Debug.
When I run it in Release, my program executes, but then 'freezes'. Pausing the execution in Visual Studio tells me the program is sitting at my while statement. The Immediate window tells me that `die` has a value of 0, and that `die > 0` is false.

Why is my loop not terminating?

## Update 1:

Here is a somewhat-close example that isnt actually my program and may or may not show the problem because it's a race condition.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace SOExample
{

    static class Program
    {
        static IConfigurationRoot appsettings;
        static int die;
        static HttpClient client;

        static void Main()
        {
            appsettings = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(Directory.GetParent(AppContext.BaseDirectory).FullName).AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true).Build();
            client = new HttpClient();
            die = 1;
            Function1();
            while (die > 0) { }
        }

        static async void Function1()
        {
            await client.GetAsync("http://google.com"); //Just to clear the async error;
            //Do Func1 Stuff
            if (appsettings.GetValue<bool>("doFunc2"))
            {
                die++;
                Function2();
            }
            die--;
        }

        static async void Function2()
        {
            //Do Other Function Stuff
            await client.GetAsync("http://google.com"); //Just to clear the async error;
            die--;
        }
    }
}
```

Following the answer below from Basic below, I replaced all the die modifiers with Interlock expressions to make them atomic, but it did not break the condition. I have tried a couple of solutions that *appear* to work; `Thread.Sleep(1000);` inside the loop body, and changing the while condition to being `!Equals(die,0)` (presumably, to lock down the value and compare it atomically), which both *seem* to work, although clearly I need to rethink the design as a whole.

Comment: Sounds like you have a race condition. We will need to see more code to help you debug it. Can you try to prepare a [mcve]?

Comment: Another potential issue... Your `die` variable isn't flagged `volatile`. This will definitely be a difference with DEBUG builds (very simplistically, it indicates the variable may be changed by multiple threads and thus each should re-fetch the "real" value rather than relying on a local cache. It also limits the optimisations that can be added by the compiler (commands can be re-ordered if they don't impact flow in a single thread). It's a little more involved than that, but the upshot is you need to use it) https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/volatile

Comment: Declare `die` as `static volatile int die;`. A likely reason here is that the compiler is optimizing your while loop to read the variable once outside the loop and never again, making it an infinite loop. Declaring it volatile prevents the compiler from optimizing it like that.

Comment: Marc, people on Stackoverflow are volunteering their time and we have no obligation to help you. Especially if your question doesn't provides too little background information for us to easily help you. Don't be rude to the people on the site.

Answer (score 4):

`die++` and `die--` are not thread safe.

Internally they're multi-step operations... read, increment/decrement, write.

If two threads do the same operation at the same time, they're likely to miscount.

Say die is on `5`. Threads 1 and 2 both try to execute `die--` simultaneously.

- Thread 1 reads `die` as 5
- Thread 2 reads `die` as 5
- Thread 1 updates `die` to be 4
- Thread 2 updates `die` to be 4 (again)

Classic race condition.

That's far less likely to happen in DEBUG mode (but not impossible) as there's more checking of threads, and more overhead in general, meaning you're much less likely to have two threads execute the same command simultaneously.

You should be using `Interlocked.Increment(ref die)` and `Interlocked.Decrement(ref die)`

Those will add/subtract 1 in a thread-safe manner.

Another potential issue...

Your `die` variable isn't declalred `volatile`.

This will definitely be a difference with DEBUG builds

Very simplistically, it indicates the variable may be changed by multiple threads and thus each should re-fetch the "real" value rather than relying on a local cache.

It also limits the optimisations that can be added by the compiler (in single-threaded operation, the compiler can re-order statements to optimise CPU efficiency, so long as they don't impact the result. This can be a lot harder to guess in multi-threaded apps and the compiler will often get it wrong).

It's a little more involved than that, but the upshot is you need to use it

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/volatile

Comment: I replaced all of the ++ and --'s with Interlocked equivilants, but ended up with the same problem.

The problem seems to center around my while loop - setting the condition of the while to `!Equals(die,0)` seems to work (after replacing the ++'s and --'s with Interlock operations), but is that the *right* solution?

Comment: The right solution™ is quite a way from here. For a start, your main thread (doing the While loop) is stuck in a tight loop, eating up CPU cycles and doing no work. You need to look into "Semaphores and Mutexes" as a topic. Specifically, you want to look at using `AutoResetEvent`s to signal between threads (so your while loop would include a call to `dieAutoResetEventEvent.WaitOne(1000))`.  That way your main thread blocks and only bothers to check the count on `die` when another thread has changed it (and signalled the main thread by calling `dieAutoResetEventEvent.Set()`). It's a big topic